# MAMP: enabling xdebug won't work - can't find php.ini

Tags: php, mamp, xdebug

I have MAMP 4.5 on a Macbook High Sierra.
I just tried to enable xdebug, mainly to make var_dump() look more readable... and I was trying to get the orange-looking Errors.
I had this on another Computer before but can't get it working this time.

My active PHP Version is 7.2.1. (which php info tells me:

```
phpinfo tells me, /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1/conf/php.ini
```

)
I can find the php.ini file in /Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.2.1
but the other php.ini file I need to edit, which should be in /Applications/MAMP/conf/php7.2.1 is not there - the latest Folder is php7.1.12 - and editing this is not doing anything.

I have the following settings (in both files):

```
display_errors = On

[xdebug]
zend_extension="/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.1.12/lib/php/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20160303/xdebug.so"
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=localhost
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.remote_autostart=1
xdebug.profiler_enable=0
xdebug.profiler_output_dir="/Applications/MAMP/tmp"
```

Comment: Why don't you edit the file you've found? Have you restarted your webserver after changing the configuration?

Comment: I edited the php7.2.1 and the php7.1.12 file. And restarted MAMP more times.

Comment: What I always find helpful with PHP extensions is to call the corresponding CLI like "php -v". If there are any errors, they will be reported on the shell (console) rather than being written to some logfile.

Comment: This is not about errors/log-files - mainly I was trying to get an readable output of var_dump() where I pass eg. an object or array.

Comment: @YetiCGN the shell version of PHP does not use the same configuration files, and not each application is able to run in the shell without changes